# How to divide a whole column by a single value and pivot horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table: The month column is each month of 2019. Assigned column represents the amount assigned to an account in their respective month. So for 01-2019, the account was assigned 35000.
cumulative_jan column shows how much of the assigned amount is collected in the given month. The 0-->11 columns represent how much time has passed since assignment. I need to check, for each passing month since the month of assignment, how much has been collected. For the 01-2019 values, I need to divide 100 by 35000 and replace the first NULL value under [0]. Next, I need to divide 250 by 35000 and replace the first NULL value under [1] etc. At the end, I have to divide 1500 by 35000 and replace the first NULL under [11].

```
Month    Assigned   cumulative_jan         0     1     2     3  ...   11
01-2019   35000           100             NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL
02-2019   16500           250             NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL
.           .              .        
.           .              .
.           .              .
12-2019   87520          1500             NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL
```

Comment: What do you mean "the first row of NULLs"? Do you mean "first column"? Please show the results you want.  Also, *text tables* are much, much preferred over images.

Comment: Hello @GordonLinoff. I updated my question with more detail and a table.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an update:

```
update t
    set [0] = assigned / cumulative_jan ;
```

Comment: That is what this does.